Salary negotiation before joining
I have signed my offer 2 weeks before but unfortunately later I got to know that the company is paying high for the freshers, but I have 2 yrs experience already. Can I negotiate my compensation now before one week of my joining date?

If you have signed an offer, that includes your compensation - whilst you could, it would be seen as unwise
So, there is nothing wrong with trying it, but the likelihood of you getting a favourable outcome is pretty much Nil.
This is one of those scenarios where although what the company is doing is a little bit scummy, it is your duty to research this sort of information before hand when negotiating your salary.

Risk versus Reward.
They offered (and you accepted) the pay rate of someone with no experience.
You have 2 years experience. This is a fairly wide disconnect.
Going back to them and pointing this out shows that you didn't bother to do the homework on the company that you should have - BEFORE interviewing.
However, pointing it out shows initiative. Taking the tack of "Mr/Ms 'so and so' didn't really take into account my experience when giving me this offer. Do you think we can review this?". Along with a "My productivity will be at the level of the experience that I already have."
Risk => Can sour your relationship with your future employer
Reward => Get more money
Being on the otherside of this, I haven't held it against the employee. No telling how these folks are.
Let us know what you choose to do.
